# Optimal Capacity of Wireless Relaying

Tags: relay, signal, wireless, capacity

"Optimal approach to relaying occurs when transmission is recieved simultaneously at the destination and relay." Is this still valid in the light of recent research? Are there trade-offs involved?

This question is motivated by the statement in (DOI:10.1109/VETECF.2002.1040432) where the author stated in the introduction that " The reason for this is that in traditional relaying, packets are only relayed through a single path. However, the optimal method of relaying [2] uses a different approach: the transmission is received simultaneously at the destination and relay"

[2] Cover, T., & Gamal, A. E. (1979). Capacity theorems for the relay channel. IEEE Transactions on information theory, 25(5), 572-584.

Comment: I highly believe the answer is "yes, if your relay channel meets the assumptions stated in the paper". For one thing, it is assumed to be memoryless. Is it?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dmitry Grigoryev, it is assumed for a typical network setting such as adhoc networks (or possibly D2D networks) "where the relay can transmit resolution information to clarify to the reciecer the previous transmission".

Comment: This paper isn't generally available without signing onto the website or being a member. This makes it a bad fit in my opinion, for this site.

Comment: Actually, the cited portion of the first paper can be accessed on the website. Its the early part of the introduction. Similarly, its possible check google scholar for both papers and find the versions that could be freely accessed.